# Criar função "dark" no site!

Tags: javascript, localstorage, temas

Estou desenvolvendo um site e queria implementar aquela famosa função “dark” para que o usuario possa escolher.

Pesquisando e garimpando nossa querida internet, consegui ter um certo resultado, criei o tal botão “Dark” e de quebra o “Ligth”.

[image: Imagem dos botões]

Porem todas ás vezes que a pagina da refresh o site volta ao padrão (branco mesmo).
Meu desejo é fixar essa função para que ela não seja mais alterada.
Gostaria de uma ajudinha de vocês mestres!

Segue o código do que já está pronto:

**HTML**

```
<body id=“bg”>
…
div>
<button onclick=“light()” type=“button” >Tema Light</button>
<button onclick=“dark()” type=“button” >Tema Dark</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function dark()
{
document.getElementById(‘bg’).style.background=’#212121 center center no-repeat’;
}
function light()
{
document.getElementById(‘bg’).style.background=’#e6e6e6 center center no-repeat’;
}
```

Comment: Você vai ter que armazenar a informação em um cookie ou no seu banco de dados e setar quando estiver carregando a página em questão

Comment: Não entendi o uso de `id` na tag `body`. Vc vai ter mais de um `body` na página?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mudar o estilo/tema do site e armazená-lo no LocalStorage](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347674/mudar-o-estilo-tema-do-site-e-armazen%c3%a1-lo-no-localstorage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria diferente, usando classes CSS e apenas uma função para alternar entre os temas. Basta criar no CSS as duas classes, `.dark` e `.light`:

```
.dark{
   background: #212121 center center no-repeat;
}

.light{
   background: #e6e6e6 center center no-repeat;
}
```

Nos botões, você chama a mesma função passando como parâmetro o nome de cada classe:

```
<button onclick="tema('light')" type="button" >Tema Light</button>
<button onclick="tema('dark')" type="button" >Tema Dark</button>
```

E a função recebe o nome da classe e adiciona no `body` e cria o localStorage:

```
function tema(t){
   document.body.classList.add(t)
   localStorage.setItem("tema", t);
}
```

Ao carregar a página, você verifica se o localStorage com o nome `tema` tem algum valor e adiciona a classe no `body` com o valor salvo:

```
var ls = localStorage.getItem("tema");
if(ls) document.body.classList.add(ls);
```

Desta forma, o `body` ficará com uma das duas classes se o `localStorage.getItem("tema")` existir e tiver valor. Por exemplo:

```
<body class="dark">
```

A vantagem de colocar uma classe no `body` é que você pode depois, se quiser, alterar outros elementos do `body`, como, por exemplo, alterar a cor do texto da página para branco adicionando `color: #fff` na classe `.dark`:

```
.dark{
   background: #212121 center center no-repeat;
   color: #fff;
}
```

> **Só uma obs.:** não precisa colocar `id` na tag `body`. Já que o `body` é único na página, basta usar `document.body`, como coloquei
>   acima.

Comment: Cara isso solucionou perfeitamente o meu problema, muito obrigado, tmj

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar *cookies* ou a API do `localStorage`. Nessa resposta, demonstrarei como usar o `localStorage` para persistir dados pelo front-end.

```js
const lightButton = document.querySelector('#light-theme-trigger');
const darkButton = document.querySelector('#dark-theme-trigger');

// Adicionamos os listeners:
lightButton.addEventListener('click', () => setTheme('light'));
darkButton.addEventListener('click', () => setTheme('dark'));

// Criamos a função que irá ficar responsável pela troca do tema:
function setTheme(themeName) {
  // Salvamos no localStorage:
  localStorage.setItem('site-theme', themeName);

  // E aqui você pode fazer o que quiser com o nome do tema,
  // como aplicar os estilos.
}

// Executamos a função sempre que a página é carregada, passando
// o tema salvo no `localStorage`. Note que usei o `light` como
// fallback caso nenhum estiver definido no storage.
setTheme(localStorage.getItem('site-theme') || 'light');
```

Basicamente, o `localStorage` tem seus métodos para obter e definir um valor (outros também, os quais não citarei aqui).

- `localStorage.getItem`: Retorna o valor armazenado. Caso não houver, retornará `null`.
- `localStorage.setItem`: Define um valor. Você deve passar no primeiro argumento a chave e no segundo, o valor.

Para saber mais sobre o `localStorage`, consulte:

- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage);
- [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage) — aqui você poderá conferir os métodos.

> **Nota:** É importante enfatizar que não é recomendado usar o `localStorage` para armazenar nenhuma informação importante, como senhas ou afins, já que pode ser acessado facilmente pelo cliente através das ferramentas do desenvolvedor.

Comment: Muito obrigado Luiz a partir do seu modo de vista pude aprender um pouco mais! Tmj

Answer (score 0):

> Galera, postei isso em outro fórum e um user chamado wldomiciano me
>   deu a seguinte solução:

Não precisa forçar o refresh. Acredito que o problema esteja na função tema().

Nela vc apenas adiciona a nova classe, mas é importante remover a classe antiga.

```
function tema(t){
  const ls = localStorage.getItem("tema");

  if(ls) document.body.classList.remove(ls);

  document.body.classList.add(t)
  localStorage.setItem("tema", t);
}
```

Acredito que com o trecho acima vc consiga resolver este problema e voltar a usar `<button>` ao invés de `<a>`.

> Realmente funcionou então estou compartilhando aqui com vcs ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Pequena observação:
antes do botão eu coloquei

```
<a href="index.html">
```

Para que sempre houvesse refresh no site, pois notei que quando clicamos por exemplo no "dark" dps do "light" e depois no "dark" dnv ele não armazenada a 3ª situação, mas quando dava refresh ele aplicava a cor.